# C++: What does this code do? foo([](){bar();});

Tags: c++, syntax, brackets, curly-braces, braces

I just came across a piece of that I am not able to properly look up on Google.
It basically looks like this `foo([](){bar();})`.
Here is what I actually found:

```
ArduinoOTA.onStart([]() {
    Serial.println("Start");
});
```

Could someone explain this syntax to me or at least tell me what I'm looking at here?

Comment: Thanks for marking this. I really hate myself for no having known about lambda functions before. They seem to be ridiculously useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [lambda expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

In this case, it seems to be registering an action to be performed on start.

Answer (score 1):

It just invokes some function `foo` with lambda function `[]() { bar(); }` as its argument.